# How to add multiple rows of data to a single column of an existing instance of a model? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hi so I've a view linked to a form, to a model. I'd like to make it so that when I update one of those fields (current-command). It adds that data to another field (Executed_Commands). So then when I add another command later to that models via the form, which will update the Current_Commands field. It will simply add another row entry to the Executed_commands column. Rather then delete the data already in that column and replace it.

**models.py (relevant section)**

```
CHOICES = [
    ('Sleep', "Sleep"),
    ('Open SSH_Tunnel', 'Open SSH_Tunnel'),
    ('Close SSH_Tunnel', 'Close SSH_Tunnel'),
    ('Open TCP_Tunnel', 'Open TCP_Tunnel'),
    ('Close TCP_Tunnel', 'Close TCP_Tunnel'),
    ('Open Dynamic', 'Open Dynamic'),
    ('Close Dynamic', 'Close Dynamic'),
    ('Task', 'Task'),
]


class Command_Node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(Beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True),
    Executed_Commands = models.CharField('Executed_Commands', max_length=2000, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)
```

**forms.py (relevant section)**

```
class Command_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Command_Node
        fields = (
            'host_id',
            'current_commands'
        )

        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=Beacon.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            choices=CHOICES
        )
```

**views.py (relevant section)**

```
def update(request, host_id):
    host_id = Command_Node.objects.get(pk=host_id)
    form = Command_Form(request.POST or None, instance=host_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    
    
    return render (request, 'update.html', {'host_id':host_id,'form':form})
```

Any idea on how I would do this?. As I can find info on how to update a field, but not on how to simply add to a column, rather then replace the rows of that models columns with a new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need a many2one on `Executed_Commands` (it's now a model

```py
class Executed_Command(models.Model):
    Command_node = models.ForeignKey(Command_Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    command = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True)

class Command_Node(models.Model):
    host_id = models.ForeignKey(Beacon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_commands = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True),

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.host_id)
```

So now you can have a `Command_Node` with a lot of `Executed_Command`

So, you need to add to Command_Form a `save`

```py
class Command_Form(ModelForm):
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        Executed_Command.objects.create(
            command=self.cleaned_data["current_commands"],
            Command_node=self.instance
        )
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

When you save your Form, before changing the `current_commands` (typo in your code pasted on StackOverFlow) we create an executed command, so now when you have your `Command_Form` you can use :

```py
command_form = Command_Form.objects.first()
command_form.Executed_command_set.all() # <- not sure with all _ and Maj here
```

Comment: Hey thanks for insight very useful. I implemented it and have gotten an attribute error. 


AttributeError: type object 'Command_Form' has no attribute 'objects'


Update now looks like:

    host_id = Command_Node.objects.get(pk=host_id)
    form = Command_Form(request.POST or None, instance=host_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        command_form = Command_Form.objects.first()
        command_form.EC_Node_set.all()  # <- not sure with all _ and Maj here
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render (request, 'update.html', {'host_id':host_id,'form':form})

Comment: had to cut out def update(request, host_id) for comment but its there.

Comment: did you `makemigration` and `migrate` ?

Comment: and be carefull `Command_Form` is a `ModelForm` and a `Model` you have a conflict for the name, try to rename the form class name

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to respond. I have makemigration and migrate are good. I've made a new post about it so I can show the code more easily. However you've super helped me either way. If you want to have a look at that new post awesome. If not though thanks all the same as the manytoone thing really useful, the save methods also really helpful So thanks.